# How to flexible adjust the width of a column if the string is too long in FreeMarker template?

Tags: html, css, templates, netsuite, freemarker

I am facing an issue of designing a PDF template with FreeMarker for NetSuite.
The template has a column whose title is "Serial Number".

The code in the template is as the following:

```
<table class="itemtable">
    <#list record.item as item>
        <#if item_index==0>
            <thead>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th colspan="1">#</th>
                    <th colspan="4">${item.item@label}</th>
                    <th align="left">${item.quantity@label}</th>
                    <th align="left">${item.description@label}</th>
                    <th align="left">${item.serial_num@label}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </#if>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">${item_index+1}</td>
            <td colspan="4">${item.item}</td>
            <td align="right">${item.quantity}</td>
            <td align="left">${item.description}</td>
            <td align="left">${item.serial_num}</td>
        </tr>
    </#list>
</table>
```

If the serial number's length is shorter than its header's title "Serial Number", the width of the column will not change.

But if the serial number(E.g. AB-795-1245-SER-572)'s length is longer than its header's title(Serial Number), then the width of the column should extend to show the whole value(AB-795-1245-SER-572) in one line(no line break).

However, currently, the width will not change even the value is longer than the title.
I have no idea about its CSS, could anybody give me a suggestion? Thank you!

**Update: Description**

Now the issue is changed as follows:

The third column should be dynamically extended depending on the value's length and has a fixed interval to the second column.

The second column has a fixed width. And the table should be aligned to the right.

```
<table style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">SubTotal</td>
        <td align="right">${subtotal}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">Tax</td>
        <td align="right">${tax}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">Total</td>
        <td align="right">${total}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

How should we implement it? Is it a good idea to use "colspan" attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the CSS "white-space" property.

```
<table class="itemtable">
    <#list record.item as item>
        <#if item_index==0>
            <thead>
                <tr valign="top">
                    <th colspan="1">#</th>
                    <th colspan="4">${item.item@label}</th>
                    <th align="left">${item.quantity@label}</th>
                    <th align="left">${item.description@label}</th>
                    <th align="left">${item.serial_num@label}</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </#if>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="1">${item_index+1}</td>
            <td colspan="4">${item.item}</td>
            <td align="right">${item.quantity}</td>
            <td align="left">${item.description}</td>
            <td style="white-space: nowrap;" align="left">${item.serial_num}</td>
        </tr>
    </#list>
</table>
```

---

**Update: Example**

When I add this to my template:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr valign="top">
            <th colspan="1">#</th>
            <th colspan="4">Item</th>
            <th align="left">Quantity</th>
            <th align="left">Description</th>
            <th align="left">Serial Num</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="1">1</td>
        <td colspan="4">Item A</td>
        <td align="right">200</td>
        <td align="left">asdf asdfasdfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdfasdf asdf asdf asdfasdfasdf asdf</td>
        <td style="white-space: nowrap;" align="left">AB-795-1245-SER-572 AB-795-1245-SER-572</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I get this:[image]

Comment: It works for me.  I added the example I used to my answer.

Comment: hi user3075978, the issue is changed.